# Web Service Date Time Parameter won't accept UK format DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: c#, web-services

I have created a Web Service and deployed it on an internal server here. The server is set to UK datetime format.

The Web Service contains one method with the following signature:

```
public Result Scan(string value, string data, DateTime ScanDateTime)
{
}
```

When testing the webservice locally on the server, it will only accept values for the 3rd parameter in American datetime format. I need to work with UK date time format but I can't find a way to change this. All accounts and system locale are set to UK format.

Comment: What webservice? What user accounts? Are you asking a question? See the link for hints on asking questions here: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Please give more information. A web service should be using a standardized format to start with.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the question

Comment: "it will only accept values for the 3rd parameter in American datetime format" - the third parameter is a DateTime, and doesn't have an intrinsic format - the format comes into play when a DateTime is converted to/from a string using cultural settings.  I suspect that what you mean is that a client you are using to connect to the WS is only accepting values in American datetime format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the culture being used at runtime, however i'd strongly suggest holding a standardized format of `yyyy-MM-dd` since all cultures understand this format.

Answer (score 1):

Because Web Service server-side code for input uses local culture settings which are different from `en-GB`, i.e. `en-US`.

But output data becomes formatted using client culture settings.

Input format should be documented by server maintainers and you should follow them.

Some DateTime conversion examples:

```
DateTime enGb = DateTime.ParseExact("02/09/2010", "dd/MM/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-GB"));

string enUS_full = enGb.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US")); // 9/2/2010 12:00:00 AM
string enUS_date = enGb.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); // 9/2/2010
string iso = enGb.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); // 2010-09-02
```

also you can use not hard-coded format but pre-configured:

```
string enUS = enGb.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern); // 9/2/2010
string iso = enGb.ToString(CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern); // 2010-09-02
```

Comment: Are these local culture settings set anywhere, in a config file?

Comment: Client culture settings are taken from Windows settings, i.e. `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` is `new CultureInfo("en-GB")`. If you want to change the outgoing data format, do a convert. I'll update my post.

Comment: I have full control over the server. it's the conversion of the input parameter that is the issue. 

I would've thought there'd be a way to configure the server / Webservice to accept the UK date format by default without having to resort to anything in code.

Comment: it's also worth mentioning that unless I change the signature for the datetime parameter to a string it won't even get as far as the code since it can't parse the UK date format into the required DateTime parameter

Comment: @Mark: I recommend to use ISO format on both sides because its a best-practice because you escape from the reason of the problem. Using one standardized, common datetime format `yyyy-MM-dd`